# ExtJs: Best List component ? Grid is way too much functionality

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, extjs5

I am trying to add a component to my window that has similar functionality to the grid but without all the selecting etc. It kind of seems overkill, I know you can disable grid selection etc but I was hoping for something similar.

Basically I have a store that has a field that contains a collection of text strings.

I would like to display the following info

```
    Text Item Name: bcdef
    Text Item Date:  25/04/2015
```

the name and date are in each record in the collection in the model. So I need to REPEAT over the above for 'n' number of records. I looked at the Dataview but it seems to support html templates not x-types.

Resulting screen would be something like so:

```
    Text Item Name: bcdef
    Text Item Date:  12/04/2015

    Text Item Name: jtjrt
    Text Item Date:  02/04/2015

    Text Item Name: bcrjtrtjrtdef
    Text Item Date:  04/04/2015

    Text Item Name: bcdef
    Text Item Date:  25/04/2015
```

How can I achieve this? The list doesn't need to be clickable, selectable or anything. It's just a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a simple panel with an XTemplate that loops through your records and writes the information you need. The result would be simple html, depending on how complex you make your template.

[XTemplate in docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate)

You'd simply need to define the Xtemplate as the panel's tpl and update the panel with the records/store.

If you find this helpful but need a bit more i may be able to provide a working sample later.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but isn't there something I can use so I can add Items (xtypes) rather than pure html template?

Comment: If you can provide a working sample,that would be great

Comment: I would defiantly go with a panel and use an xtemplate.  we have done this on several components that were complex visuals but were mostly just readonly data.  its pretty easy and you can produce a great result.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help.